# Required EditText Android Not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-studio

I'm trying to create a required EditText, i'm trying it with a boolean but it doesn't work.
Neither the setError doesn't dissapears when I type something on my EditText, only on the txtEdat, txtTelefon, txtEmail...
And the boolean seems like it's useless on this code because only recognize the txtEmail (The last one)...

```
boolean contador;
contador = false;
//Creem el intent

Intent iIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, FormEnviado.class);
//Creem un bundle que es on anira la informació que es pasarà a la altre activity
Bundle bBundle = new Bundle();
// si isChecked el valor es True
bBundle.putBoolean("cbValidator", cbDades.isChecked());

// En cada if mirem si hi ha algun camp buit
bBundle.putString("cognom", txtCognom.getText().toString());
if(txtCognom.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    contador = false;
    txtCognom.setError("Aquet camp no pot estar buit");
}
else
{
    contador = true;
}

bBundle.putString("nom", txtNom.getText().toString());

if(txtNom.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    contador = false;
    txtNom.setError("Aquet camp no pot estar buit");
}
else
{
    contador = true;
}

bBundle.putString("edat", txtEdat.getText().toString());
if(txtEdat.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    contador = false;
    txtEdat.setError("Aquet camp no pot estar buit");
}
else
{
    contador = true;
}

bBundle.putString("telefon", txtTelefon.getText().toString());

if(txtTelefon.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    contador = false;
    txtTelefon.setError("Aquet camp no pot estar buit");
}
else
{
    contador = true;
}

bBundle.putString("email", txtEmail.getText().toString());

if(txtEmail.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    contador = false;
    txtEmail.setError("Aquet camp no pot estar buit");
}
else
{
    contador = true;
}

// Toast i no ens deixarà enviar-lo 
if (!contador)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has de omplir el formulair per enviar-lo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// Formulario omplert
else
{
    //Afegim la informació de bundle al intent
    iIntent.putExtras(bBundle);
    //Inicialitzem el intent
    startActivity(iIntent);
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: you can use `intent` instead of `iIntent`.

Comment: I know right, but i think it doesn't change anything on my issue...

Comment: You want that all the fields will be required (not empty) ?

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code is incorrect. You have four checks like this:

```
if (required field is empty) {
    contador = false;
} else {
    contador = true
}
```

If the last check (which evaluates `txtEmail`) passes, then `contador` will be true, even if the other checks did not pass.

Initialize `contador` to `true` and remove the `else` blocks on all four of these checks. If they all pass, `contador` will still be `true`.

Comment: Uh, my bad.... I am appreciative of your help, the last thing i don't know how to fix is the setError only dissapears on Edat, Telefon and E-mail, on Nom and Cognom still with the Pop-up... any solution?

Comment: The popup goes away when you call `setError(null)`. Are you doing that?

Comment: No, I mean when I try to send the form with empty fields, it appears a lot of popups, that's what I want, but when I start to type it only dissapears in Edat, Email, Telefon, i'm wondering if I use "android:inputType="textCapWords" and "android:inputType="textCapSentence" it doesn't dissapears...